# LMDE with gnome 3 - Change automount options

Tags: linux, gnome, fstab, automount

I've got GNOME 3 on an LMDE machine and I need to change the automount options to mount **without** the **noexec** attribute for an NTFS partition. Does anyone know where I could find such configurations and which tool is responsible for the automounting? I don't have gnome-mount or gnome-volume-ontrol installed and I know you could probably use **/etc/fstab** but that would cause a lot of problems and doesn't seem to be responsible for the automounting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about USB drives, NFS shares, samba or what? I assume USB?

Comment: Are you actually seeing `noexec` in /proc/mounts, or only guessing that it might be set?

Comment: @terdon It's USB and other system partitions.

Comment: @grawity I was only guessing because I'm not able to add the executable attribute in the partition with CHMOD. I just checked the file you said. It doesn't have noexec but has default_permissions. Could it be because of that? this is the full line: /dev/sda5 /media/NewVolume fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-mounting is done by GNOME Shell (which watches for new storage devices) and *udisks2* (which performs the actual mounting). *udisks* adds such options as `nodev` and `nosuid`, and filters user-provided options. However, I could not find *any* place that would add `noexec` by default.

The actual problem is that NTFS filesystems are always mounted with permission support by default – since Windows SIDs cannot be automatically mapped to Unix accounts without manual configuration (creating the `UserMapping` file in ntfs-3g).

For an internal partition used in Windows, you can try to automatically generate the mapping using `ntfs-3g.usermap`, or create it manually as described in [ntfs-3g(8)](/media/NewVolume/.NTFS-3G).

```
john::S-1-5-21-3141592653-589793238-462643383-1008
mary::S-1-5-21-3141592653-589793238-462643383-1009
:smith:S-1-5-21-3141592653-589793238-462643383-513
```

Another option – best for USB drives – is to create a "mapping" that assigns a fresh SID to all Unix UIDs, without manually translating each user name.

```
mkdir /media/NewVolume/.NTFS-3G

a=$[RANDOM*RANDOM]; b=$[RANDOM*RANDOM]; c=$[RANDOM*RANDOM]

echo "::S-1-2-5-21-$a-$b-$c-10000" > /media/NewVolume/.NTFS-3G/UserMapping

umount /media/NewVolume
```

The UserMapping will be enabled on next mount.

---

Note that if you are talking about partitions of an internal disk, `/etc/fstab` **would not** cause problems – it is in fact **the recommended way**. Automounting is primarily only for removable disks.

Comment: my problem with /etc/fstab is that I can't mount any entry without root and nautilus can't mount it. This is the line I added in fstab:/dev/sda5 /media/NewVolume fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,exec,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0

Comment: @Auxiliary: Entries in fstab are mounted *automatically* on boot, unless you have added a `noauto` option. That said, the line you added was incorrect (regardless of what `/etc/mtab` says). For NTFS, add `/dev/sda5 /media/NewVolume ntfs defaults 0 0`.